# Removing white blank space on top after NoActionBar

Tags: android-studio, android-actionbar

I am trying to get rid of white blank space on the top after removing action bar, but It is keep living a white space no matter what I try I have NoActionbar, windowNoTitle true
windowActionbar false windowActibaroverlay true but it does not remove the white blank space on where the actionbar was
[image: it is emulator that shows blank space on top][image: my theme file][image: parent of my theme file]

Comment: Please show your layout.xml